# Is it safe to install maximum supported RAM?

Tags: memory

My motherboard supports maximum 8GB of RAM. Is it safe to install full 8GB?

It's a Core 2 Duo E7200 processor and Gigabyte GA G41 MT S2P motherboard.

Comment: safe yes, can it sometimes be pickey to get it working the same as your present configuration, yes. Your question would be much better for you , if you would provide all the specs of the system.

Comment: Its a Core 2 Duo E7200 processor and Gigabyte GA G41 MT S2P motherboard

Comment: I would advise you to use the memory recommended by the motherboard manufacturer rather than taking a mix'n'match approach. Visit their website and look for the memory QVL associated with your motherboard.

Comment: I know what specification ram I should use . But I dont want to mess up my system . Some of my friends said just to be on the safe side install 6gb ram .

Comment: That's nonsense. If you wanted to install *more* than the supported maximum, you *might* run into problems; installing the maximum *supported* should be fine (seeing that you know what specific RAM modules you should use).

Comment: From what I've heard, the reported maximum (8 GB) is *already* "on the safe side"...

Answer (score 5):

Probably; the only foreseeable problem would be that your CPU and operating system both need to be 64-bit to use all of it. (Barring any specific reasons why you are asking, it is generally safe to add ram.)

Comment: Its a Core 2 Duo E7200 processor and Gigabyte GA G41 MT S2P motherboard

Comment: e7200 supports 64-bit. operating system?

Comment: yupp it does support 64 bit

Comment: FWIW, Processors have been supporting 64 bit operating systems for the better part of this century.

Comment: I not knocking this down, or complaining. But there are "ways" to use 8gig in a 32bit system :-) you can still create a ramdisk in extended space for other uses.   there is nothing unsafe about having more ram in any system that I am aware of, I can even run win98 after blocking out the ram it cannot cope with. And putting to much ram on a board that does not support it does not break the ram itself or hurt the user :-) or damage the motherboard, it just wont work in that configuration of ram chips.

Comment: ~surfasb, yeah I was meaning mostly the operating system. (Although "this century" *is* only a decade so far.) ~Psycogeek, I did not know that; neat. -- Also, superuser is being buggy, so s/@/~/.